# Preventing ArcGIS Online from truncating long field names?

Tags: attribute-table, arcgis-online, limitations

According to the [File Geodatabase Size Limits](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/file-geodatabase-size-and-name-limits.htm) document, a field name can be up to 64 characters long:

> Field name length: 64 characters

I have a standalone fGDB table containing a column with a name 38 chars wide. The field's alias is the same as the field name.

[image]

I add this to an ArcMap document containing a single polygon layer, and publish the MXD to ArcGIS Online. The ArcGIS Online REST endpoint for the standalone table shows that the field name has been truncated to 31 characters long.

[image]

Is this a bug with ArcGIS Online, or is there a workaround?

Comment: Have you been able to replicate this with another dataset?

Comment: I have. Tested on both a table and a feature class. Same results as of Stephen. Probably a good time to talk to tech support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it sounds like you are hitting a limitation with ArcGIS Online, which has been reproduced by @AlexTereshenkov, I think you should submit your test to Esri's technical support and ask them to verify whether it is a hard limit that they can document, a bug which they will work to address, or a current limit that they will entertain as an enhancement request.

If you are able to get a bug number, then I think it would be useful for you to post that with a summary of how Esri describe the issue as a self-answer to your question.